# updating all element's which have text instantly after localization

Tags: localization, swift4

I have a problem with localization

I want to use be able to change language off app between English and Arabic
I know that at the first I must have two localization.strings one for "en" and one for "ar" and when user clicked at the button i change path of bundle 
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V0PP.png][1]

but after all of these( when i change path of bundle ) , I don't know how to be able to change all texts on all over the app  instantly.  I just want to change text. I do not care about about alignment and images and ...

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/T665i.png][2]

Could you explain how? I'm totally confused and I don't want to hard-code like `text.localized()` for every text and have outlet for every single one because I think it's not proper to repeat something over and over.